# Is it possible, in Android, to remove a String from RAM?

Tags: java, android, string, security

The nature of a String in Java is immutable, therefore, a new value attribution for a existent variable will result in a new String. Saying that, can I null or zero that old String?

I'm asking because there's no guarantee the Garbage Collector will clean up even if I call it, at the time I want.

The point here is security: a String in memory could be retrieved in a compromised device, right?

Comment: A common solution to this problem is to use a `char[]` rather than a string. Then you fill it with spaces as soon as you've finished with it and you don't need to care when it gets garbage collected.

Comment: @cppbeginner For cases where you can use a char[] instead a String. In an EditText, for instance, it's not possible...

Comment: May be of interest: http://www.javacreed.com/how-to-modify-a-string-without-creating-a-new-one/

Comment: I don't know if this answer is correct, but it's definitely relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15844273/6253321

Comment: @PatrickParker Very interesting reading. Worth it!

Comment: @cppbeginner A fast search in EditText source code which extends TextView reveals that getText() method returns  mText and mText is initialized in TextView constructor as mText = "";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I null or zeroing that old String?

No.

> A String in memory could be retrieved in a compromised device, right?

Yes, but it would require a rooted device or a combination of the SDK tools and direct access to the device.

You need to decide whether your threat vectors include people who would go to those extremes.

Comment: For now, it is just a mere curiosity. Anyway, Security is both important and fascinating. Thanks.